# Economy of internet traffic using MacBook

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

Some time I will need to use mobile connection with my MacBook. I am wondering if there is any way to economy of the internet traffic on MacBook? Something like to deny access to internet for applications except the whitelisted ones.

Comment: Just run the apps you want and not the others. Make sure they are shut down.

Comment: Actually I think Little Snitch allows you to do exactly that. Deny all the low level network calls from the OS by default and then later turn them back on. Not free but an excellent well supported utility, been using it for years.

Answer (score 1):

i've had same question but later found out the answer

having the mac os Sonoma 14.1.1 this seting is located in settings -> wifi -> network settings -> low data mod ON

[image][image]